# vue js view not updates with dynamically added v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-model

I add some dynamic data to model in vuejs mounted hook but when it is mounted first time it reactivity works and view updates but when I make changes this model view not updates.

```
{
    props: {
        requestall: Object,
        category_field_options: Array,
    },
    data(){
        return {
            field_options: {},
        };
    },
    mounted(){
        for(var field of this.category_field_options)
        {
            var data = [];

            for(var option of field.options)
            {
                if(this.check_option_is_selected(field.id, option.id) ) // true
                {
                    data.push(option.id);
                }
            }


            this.field_options['field_' + field.id] = data;

        }
    },
    methods: {
        /**
         * Dynamic category fields options checked or unchecked.
         * 
         * @param object event
         * @param int field_id
         * @param int option_id
         */
        field_option_changed(event, field_id, option_id)
        {
            if(this.field_options['field_' + field_id].indexOf(option_id) > -1){
                var index = this.field_options['field_' + field_id].indexOf(option_id);
                this.field_options['field_' + field_id].splice(index, 1);
            }else{
                this.field_options['field_' + field_id].push(option_id);
            }
        },
        /**
         * @param int
         * @param int
         * 
         * @return 
         */
        check_option_is_selected(field_id, option_id)
        {
            var check = this.requestall['field_' + field_id] 
                && (this.requestall['field_' + field_id].indexOf(option_id.toString()) > -1) 
                ? true : false;

            return check;
        },
    }
}
```

**I see changes take affect on vue chrome inspector when field_option_changed function works.
but view end not updates after these changes.** When it is mounted it works fine. 
I am not sure maybe this happens because of javascript stored variables data types 
(In JavaScript, a variable may store two types of data: primitive and reference)

```
<template>
    <div>
        <span v-for="(val,key,index) in field_options" :key="'willSubmitField_' + index">
            <input type="text" v-for="option in val" :key="'willSubmitField_' + index + '_' + option" 
                :name="key + '[]'" :value="option">
        </span>
    </div>
</template>
```

**#EDIT 1**

I find a solution with having one v-model array value and only keep selected values in it.

```
{
    props: {
        requestall: Object,
        category_field_options: Array,
    },
    data(){
        return {
            field_options: [],
        };
    },
    mounted(){
        for(var key in this.requestall)
        {
            if(key.search(/^field_\d$/i) > -1)
            {
                for(var option of this.requestall[key]){
                    this.field_options.push(parseInt(option));
                }
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        /**
         * Dynamic category fields options checked or unchecked.
         * 
         * @param object event
         * @param int option_id
         */
        field_option_changed(event, option_id)
        {
            if(this.field_options.indexOf(option_id) > -1){
                var index = this.field_options.indexOf(option_id);
                this.field_options.splice(index, 1);
            }else{
                this.field_options.push(option_id);
            }
        },
        /**
         * @param int
         * @param int
         * 
         * @return 
         */
        check_option_is_selected(field_id, option_id)
        {
            var check = this.field_options && (this.field_options.indexOf(option_id) > -1) 
            ? true : false;

        return check;
        },
    }
}
```

and changes in template

```
<template>
    <div>
        <span v-for="(field,index) in category_field_options" :key="'categoryField_' + index">
            <span v-for="option in field.options" :key="'categoryField_option' + option.id">
                <input type="text" :name="'field_' + field.id + '[]'" 
                    v-if="check_option_is_selected(field.id, option.id)" 
                    :value="option.id">
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Due to limitations of modern JavaScript, Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion. For example:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    a: 1
  }
})
// `vm.a` is now reactive

vm.b = 2
// `vm.b` is NOT reactive
```

> Vue does not allow dynamically adding new root-level reactive properties to an already created instance. However, it’s possible to add reactive properties to a nested object using the `Vue.set(object, propertyName, value)` method.

More on **Object change detection caveats** [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-Change-Detection-Caveats).